# Why is there an infinite loop here? (linked list printing)

Tags: c, loops, data-structures, infinite-loop, doubly-linked-list

I am doing a little practice with linked lists, these are the structures.

```
typedef struct roomList roomList;
typedef struct school school;
typedef struct studentList studentList;
roomList *getRoom(school* school, int class, int roomNr);

struct studentList{

    char *name;
    int class; 
    float grade;
    int roomNr;
    studentList *next;
    studentList *prev;
};


struct roomList{

    int nrOfStudents;
    int roomNr;
    studentList *students; //pointer to student list.
    roomList *next;
    roomList *prev; 
};



struct school{

    int totalStudents;
    roomList *Class[13]; //array of classes, each index contains rooms.
};
```

**This is where the infinite loop is happening, it's a function to print all students within a room.**

```
void printRoom(school *school, int class, int roomNr)
{
    roomList *room = getRoom(school, class, roomNr);
    studentList *student;

    if(room != NULL)
    {
        int i = 1;
        printf("Nr of students: %d\n", room->nrOfStudents);
        while(room->nrOfStudents != 0 && student != NULL)
        {
            student = room->students;
            printf("%d - \"%s\" ",i, student->name);
            student = student->next;
            i++;
        }
    }   
}
```

This is how I'm creating a `student`

```
studentList *createStudent(int class, char *name, int roomNr)
{
    studentList *newNode;
    newNode = (studentList*)calloc(1, sizeof(studentList));
    newNode->class  = class;
    newNode->name   = (char*)malloc(strlen(name)+1);
    strcpy(newNode->name, name);
    newNode->roomNr = roomNr;
    newNode->grade  = 0;
    newNode->next   = newNode->prev = NULL;

    return newNode;
}
```

And finally, this is how I'm inserting a `student` into a `room`.

```
void insertStudentToRoom(school* school, int class, int roomNr, char *name)
{
    roomList *room;
    room = getRoom(school, class, roomNr);
    studentList *newStudent;
    newStudent = createStudent(class, name, roomNr);

    if(room->students != NULL)
    {
        newStudent->next = room->students;
        room->students->prev = newStudent;
        room->students = newStudent;
        room->nrOfStudents++;
        school->totalStudents++;
    }
    else
    {
        room->students = newStudent;
        room->nrOfStudents++;
        school->totalStudents++;
    }
}
```

The infinite infinite loop only happens when I insert more than one `student` into a `room`, and exits fine when there's only one student, I've tried fumbling around with exit conditions for my `while()` to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    while(room->nrOfStudents != 0 && student != NULL)
    {
        student = room->students;
        printf("%d - \"%s\" ",i, student->name);
        student = student->next;
        i++;
    }
```

Look closely. You never change `room` in the loop. So `student = room->students;` is going to set the very same value for `student` every single time in the loop. If it didn't break after the first time, it won't break any other time.

You probably want to take `student = room->students;` out of the loop. You only want to point at the first student in the room once.

Comment: More precisely, `if (room->nrOfStudents != 0) { studentList *student = room->students; while (student != NULL) { ... } }`

Comment: Thank you! this shameful question is my punishment for doing kata deep into the AM.

Comment: @ikegami I like this one, my teacher always told me about avoiding compound ```if()```'s.

Comment: @Rami Raghfan, You mean avoid using `&&`? That's silly. The reason for using two statements here is because there's no point in checking `room->nrOfStudents != 0` more than once since `room` never changes.

Comment: @Rami Raghfan, One would presume that `room->students` is `NULL` when `room->nrOfStudents` is `0`, so you could simply use `studentList *student = room->students; while (student != NULL) { ... } `

Comment: oh I see! thank you very much for the clarification. but isn't avoiding ```&&``` when unnecessary better? If you don't want to answer this I can open a question for it.